# How to disable the blinking cursor in label

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="search">

    <input type="search" id="site-search"> 

</div>
```

How to hide blinking cursor after press enter?

Comment: How is the cursor blinking in a label? I am guessing we need to see code....

Comment: Could you show us the code?

Comment: blinks after clicking on an input field, wants it to hide after pressing enter

Comment: We can't see what you're seeing without a [mcve] in your question

Comment: So listen for keypress when it is enter, call blur? Seems very odd.

Comment: It would be extremely bad UX to not have a cursor in an editable text field.  For the sake of your users, don't do this.  There may be a better way to accomplish your goal if you tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the sentiment of the comments, it's odd and not good UX, but since you asked...

The following code adds a `keydown` event listener to the input, and when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, it calls `blur` on the element:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("site-search");
el.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.key === "Enter") {
      el.blur();
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aywpf0e4/

Comment: how to make this script work with that as well: var scrollOK = true;
 $("#site-search").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if((e.which == 13) && scrollOK) {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
    }, 2000);   
    scrollOK = false;
    setTimeout(function(){ scrollOK=true; }, 10000);
  }
});